# Microsoft Graph API : error 13012 when calling getAccessToken on Outlook Desktop

Tags: javascript, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm working on an Outlook Addin that uses the Microsoft Graph API. On Outlook Web it works fine, but on Outlook Desktop I'm always getting the 13012 error when I call :

```
let bootstrapToken = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({ allowSignInPrompt: true, allowConsentPrompt: true, forMSGraphAccess: true });
```

It then opens a pop up to grant permissions for my app as expected, It does return me a valid token but when I call *getAccessToken()* again to make the API call, I still get the 13012 error even after granting authorizations.

I don't understand why I get this error, reading the documentation it shouldn't be linked to Outlook Desktop.

Here is what the doc says :

> 13012 There are several possible causes:
>
> The add-in is running on a platform that does not support the
> getAccessToken API. For example, it is not supported on iPad. See also
> Identity API Requirement Sets. The forMSGraphAccess option was passed
> in the call to getAccessToken and the user obtained the add-in from
> AppSource. In this scenario, the tenant admin has not granted consent
> to the add-in for the Microsoft Graph scopes (permissions) that it
> needs. Recalling getAccessToken with the allowConsentPrompt will not
> solve the problem because Office is allowed to prompt the user for
> consent to only the AAD profile scope. Your code should fall back to
> an alternate system of user authentication.
>
> In development, the add-in is sideloaded in Outlook and the
> forMSGraphAccess option was passed in the call to getAccessToken.

I also had to bundle my app to be able to use it on Outlook Desktop because it is based on IE11. Could it be a possible cause?

Because I started my app with this repo :
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-NodeJS-SSO

And when I run the example I don't get this error, and I didn't change anything in the code of *ssoAuthES6.js* before the call to *getAccessToken()*.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you know if Modern Authentication is enabled for the Exchange organization? This is discussed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins, specifically, the part on Exchange Online: How to enable your tenant for modern authentication (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins). For Outlook Desktop, modern authentication must be enabled.

Comment: Thanks. Yes for me I think thanks to this link https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-auth-and-exchange-online-february-2020-update/ba-p/1191282  modern authentification is enabled because I'm getting the mini web-like page Modern Auth dialog. So this is not the problem I think. 

I also just checked my Outlook connection status but the Authn column has the Support* value and not Bearer*. What does this mean? Is this maybe the cause?

Are there some other possible causes for my 13012 error?

Comment: What is your version of Outlook? It is possible that you have an old build of Outlook that does not support this API.

Answer (score 0):

ssoAuthES6.js should get transpiled to ES5 which is fully supported by IE11 so I don't see a problem there. However, following by documentation:

> Setting the forMSGraphAccess option to true signals to Office that the
> add-in intends to use the bootstrap token to get an access token to
> Microsoft Graph, instead of just using it as an ID token. If the
> tenant administrator has not granted consent to the add-in's access to
> Microsoft Graph, then OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken returns error
> 13012

My guess is that you might be using a different app registration where MS Graph permissions that require admin consent (EG: Files.Read.All) have not been consented.

Keep in mind:

> Setting the allowConsentPrompt option to true means that if the user
> has not consented to let the add-in access the user's AAD profile,
> then Office will open a consent prompt. (The prompt only allows the
> user to consent to the user's AAD profile, not to Microsoft Graph
> scopes.)

Comment: I really don't understand, I use the same app registration, the same tenant Id, it is working in Outlook Web but in Desktop I get the error 13012. I added the scopes of MSGraph in the Azure Manifest it should be good. 

Do I have to fill the preAuthorizedApplications field in the Azure Manifest? I don't have access to the Azure Interface for  my company I don't have the rights so I'm using Azure CLI but I couldn't find a way to fill this.

Comment: @Walidebisi did you consent the required MS Graph permissions? Why would you need preAuthorizedApplications ? (I'm new to Office addins, may you can point some documentation to take a quick look)

Comment: Yes I did.
I Talked about preAuthorizedApplications because when I following tutorial the preAuthorizedApplications entry was filled in the Azure Manifest using the Azure Portal but I can't fill this entry with Azure CLI. I thought that if I wanted to use the Addin in Outlook Desktop I had to preAuthorize Outlook Desktop in the Azure Manifest.

Here is a tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs#register-the-add-in-with-azure-ad-v20-endpoint

The step 15 made me think it was mandatory

Answer (score 0):

According the `office.js` team if you are using `forMSGraphAccess: true` as the parameter for `getaccesstoken()` then you are expected to see the `13012 error`.

This is due to you have side loaded the `addin`, if you are using `forMSGraphAccess: true` you need to deploy the `add-in` via the `admin center`.

Please go through the git issue I raised: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2711

You can set `forMSGraphAccess: false` and call the `getaccesstoken()` and you will no longer see the `13012 error`. The good thing is that you can still use the token to make Graph API Call. I hope this helps you.